# Meaning of PPP conversion factors

Tags: exchange-rates, purchasing-power-partity

How do I interpret the numbers of this table [PPP conversion factor, GDP (LCU per international $)](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.PPP) as published by the World Bank:

[image]

First of all, it's just numbers, but what do they tell (in common words). What's the difference between

- Bahrein (0.19), a very rich country
- United States (1.0), the benchmark or reference country
- Belize (1.14), a rather poor country
- India (18.15)
- Armenia (197.04)
- Vietnam (7,792.72), a not so poor country

Which property does Vietnam have 8,000 times more than the United States and 40 times more than Armenia? What is measured?

Side questions: What for and in which contexts are these numbers used and play an effective role? Do two decimal digits really make a difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penn_effect